# System freeze on shutdown, but another similar is not my case

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, deepin-desktop-environment

I found [System freeze on reboot/shutdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530794/system-freeze-on-reboot-shutdown) , But I am a UEFI user, so I cannot use the noefi flag. Also, I am not using Nvidia graphic cards.

### System info

- CPUInfo: https://pastebin.com/raw/RH2JT7Ru
- lsGPU: https://pastebin.com/raw/fmHvW4WH
- `uname -srvmpio`: `Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Linux distro: UbuntuDDE

EDIT: <s>If I reboot from the command line, it works fine. The problem just appears when I shutdown via the dde dock icon.</s>

EDIT: The error appears again. the log: https://toyshost2.ddns.net/tmp/9pTbfA2l64Y6K8gcmcVlwVxipw.txt

EDIT: Lightdm log:https://toyshost2.ddns.net/tmp/Sx9FvpjEP5WMudRXzl6Yexirkm.txt

EDIT: The problem also happens when shutdown from the command line.

Comment: To diagnose: "shutdown via the dde dock icon". Wait 35 minutes (we're looking for a 30 minute timeout). Reboot. In a command line terminal,  `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` to see the shutdown log.

Comment: Did you mean I need to freeze 30 minutes then shutdown?

Comment: No. I mean start the shutdown (click the icon, respond to the prompts), then go away (read a book, eat lunch, play outside, ...) for at least 35 minutes.

Comment: Oh no! I hate waiting. But that is a good free time to finish my work XD

Comment: My laptop shut down well now. I don't know why it becomes normal.

Comment: @waltinator The error appears again, I gave the log file.

Comment: I'm not going to read your 12.7Kb logvomit. You should read it yourself, and check the timestamps of each log entry.

Comment: How to know what happens by checking the log?

Comment: I found what happened. There is a lot of lines about PulseAudio.